# MySQL code locks up server

Tags: mysql

I have code that I have tested on the same table, but with only a few records in it.
It worked great on a handful (30) records. Did exactly what I wanted it to do.

When I added a 200 records to the table - it locks up. I have to restart apache and have tried waiting for ever for it to finish.

I could use some help figuring out why.

My table has the proper indexes and I am not having trouble in any other way.
Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE `base_data_test_20000_rows` SET `NO_TOP_RATING` = 

(SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`

     WHERE
     `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`ID` != `base_data_test_20000_rows`.`ID`
     AND
     `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`ANALYST` = `base_data_test_20000_rows`.`ANALYST`
     AND
     `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`IRECCD` = 
                            (SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`

                                WHERE `IRECCD` = 

                                (select MIN(`IRECCD`) FROM `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`

                                    WHERE
                                    `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED` >= DATE_SUB(`base_data_test_20000_rows`.`ANNDATS_CONVERTED`,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
                                    AND
                                    `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`ID` != `base_data_test_20000_rows`.`ID`
                                    AND
                                    `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`ESTIMID` = `base_data_test_20000_rows`.`ESTIMID`
                                )

                            )


)
WHERE `base_data_test_20000_rows`.`ANALYST` != ''
```

The code is just meant to look a year back for a particular brokerage - get the lowest rating - then count the number of times that analyst had the lowest rating. write that vale to the NO_TOP_RATING column.

Comment: Make a version that just provides the results of a SELECT without the update, and run an EXPLAIN EXTENDED on it.  What does that show you?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`IRECCD` = Count.... to `base_data_test_20000_rows_2`.`IRECCD` = somenumber to see if that effects the query speed? 

Without looking more closely, I assume what's going on is that your query simply takes too much memory or takes too long to process. If it is the latter I would suspect your count but I could be very wrong.

Comment: In other words, break your queries down and test them to see if the hang up is in a specific part of the query, or in the combination of the queries.

Comment: Your 4-level deep, re-use two almost same name tables as part of a correlated query is really bad to follow, especially on the generic "lowest" rating.  Can you dump some sample data rows from each table (changing names for privacy).  You are based on a count() of a min() of the IRECCD column.  A count coincidentally matching the IRECCD I would be concerned with.  Maybe your sample data can provide some clarification.  Get a good sample of probably AT LEAST 20 rows to show pattern you are looking for (edit original question with data)

Comment: So, far - on a few occasions - with smaller tables (5000) records - I get the error "#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction". (it is not set in a transaction) Not sure if that is what the MySQL error means.
Im working on taking some of the other advice here. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mallow - I did try what you said - on 5000 records it worked - response "3211 rows affected. (Query took 67.4246 seconds.)" on 5000000 records - this would calculate into about 1.8 hours...? Is this reasonable normal time  to take to calculate something like this? if so - how do I get that count without it bogging down like crazy?

Comment: I will also try to provide a better example here - thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Hi again @Mallow - I now tried what you suggested (base_data_test_20000_rows_2.IRECCD = 3) on all 5000000 records - it was able to update "451381 rows affected. (Query took 134.3342 seconds.)" - this seems pretty reasonable. So... now I just need to know how to get that count for each record - ... ? Thanks again

Comment: Hmm. I think it's pretty clear that your query isn't optimized to the best of what you want to do. I can only really make two or three suggestions. The first, take some time to think about what your goal is, sleep on it, and try to see if you can combine your queries into one if possible. Second you could see if creating views can help speed up. Third, you could modify the mysql settings to make the execution time longer, but there again your question of whether it will take hours becomes a concern. Forth, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I was wrong with my original suggestion, chainging the select count to it's own number won't help since you have conditions on your query

<strike>This is merely a hackish solution. The real way to solve this would be to optimize your query. But as a work around you could set the record count to a mysql variable, and then reference that variable in the query.</strike>

This means that you will have to make sure you set the count to the variable before you run the query. But this means that should records be added in between the time you set the variable and complete running the query you will not have the right count.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

further thoughts:
I took a closer look before submitting this answer. That might not actually be possible since you have the where statements which is individualized to each record.

It's slow because you are using a query that counts within a query that counts within a query that has a min. It's like you are iterating through every row three times each time you iterate through a row. Which is an exponential search. So if the database has 10 records you are possibly going through each record 10^3ish times. At the number of rows you have, it's hellish.

I'm sure that there is a way to do what you are trying to do, but I can't actually tell what you are trying to do.

I would have to agree with DRapp that seeing dummy data could help us analyze what's really going on.

Since I can't wrap my head around it all, what I would try, without fully understanding what you are doing, would be to create a view of each of your sub queries and then do a query on that. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

But that probably won't escape the redundancy, but it might help with the speed. But since I don't fully understand what you are doing, that's probably not the best answer.

Another not so good answer would be if you aren't running this on a mission critical db and it can go offline while you run the query then you could just changed your mysql settings and let this query run for those hours you quoted and hope it doesn't crash. But that seems less than ideal, as I have no idea if that requires additional disk space or memory to preform.

So really my best answer I can ever give you at this point, is try to see if you can approach your problem from a different angle. Or post some dummy data of what the info in Base_data_test_20000_rows looks like and what you expect it to look like after the query runs.

-Hope  that helps point you to the right direction

Comment: I think I have a better version of this question - maybe a better format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695035/mysql-loop-and-count-min-for-all-records